# Testing for PUT/POST/DELETE Methods

Tags: php, phpspec, tonic

I am having some trouble running tests for `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` using the unit testing framework [phpspec2](http://phpspec.net/).

This is the code that I have in my unit test:

```
$this->beConstructedWith(new \Tonic\Application(), new \Tonic\Request(array(
    'uri' => '/',
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'data' => '{"name":"testing", "email":"testing@@test.com", "password":"Passw0rd"}'
)), array());

$expectedResult = new \stdClass();
$expectedResult->message = "An error was encountered.";
$expectedResult->error[] = "The email must be valid.";

$response = $this->exec();
$response->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf("Tonic\Response");
$response->contentType->shouldBe("application/json");
$response->body->shouldBe(json_encode($expectedResult));
```

From looking around the [Tonic](http://peej.github.io/tonic/) code and the examples in the [git repository](https://github.com/peej/tonic) I think I have it set up correctly.

The following is the result of running `bin/phpspec -v run` for this unit test:

[image: phpspec2 Error]

When I run an actual request against the Tonic service it works fine. I know I must be doing something wrong in the setup of the unit test but I don't know what.

**Edit**: PUT Method

```
/**
 * Add a new user to the table.
 *
 * @method PUT
 * @accepts application/json
 * @provides application/json
 * @json
 * @return \Tonic\Response
 */
public function add()
{
    // Validate the data before we go any futher.
    $error = $this->validate();

    // If the data is invalid then we want to let the requester know.
    if (true === $error) {
        $this->output->message = "An error was encountered.";
        $this->responseCode = \Tonic\Response::NOTFOUND;
    } else { // Else we want to PUT the data into our table.
        $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `dateOfBirth`) VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :dateOfBirth)");
        $query->bindValue(":name", $this->request->data->name);
        $query->bindValue(":email", $this->request->data->email);
        $query->bindValue(":password", hash('sha256', $this->request->data->password));
        $query->bindValue(":dateOfBirth", $this->request->data->dateOfBirth);
        $query->execute();

        // Check that the new user was successfully inserted into the database. If not let the requester know what happened.
        if (0 === $query->rowCount()) {
            if ("00000" === $query->errorCode()) {
                $this->output->message = "No rows affected by query.";
            } else {
                $this->output->message = "There was an error running the query.";
                $this->output->error[] = $query->errorInfo();
            }

            $this->responseCode = \Tonic\Response::CONFLICT;
        } else { // Inserted successfully.
            $this->output->message = "User successfully created.";
            $this->responseCode = \Tonic\Response::CREATED;
            $this->headers["Location"] = "/" . $this->request->data->email;
        }
    }

    return new \Tonic\Response($this->responseCode, $this->output, $this->headers);
}
```

Comment: Which part of the exception message specifically don't you understand?

Comment: I understand that it is saying there is not method for PUT. But I don't understand why it is saying that, as there is a method for PUT. I'll add my method to the question.

Comment: Probably not for URI `/`?

Comment: The class deals with both `/` and `/:identity` URIs.

Comment: Well the exception says that no method is matching. Can you enable logging maybe? Could shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. The issue was to do with the `Content-Type` set in the following code:

```
$this->beConstructedWith(new \Tonic\Application(), new \Tonic\Request(array(
    'uri' => '/',
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'data' => '{"name":"testing", "email":"testing@@test.com", "password":"Passw0rd"}'
)), array());
```

It should be `contentType`:

```
$this->beConstructedWith(new \Tonic\Application(), new \Tonic\Request(array(
    'uri' => '/',
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'contentType' => 'application/json',
    'data' => '{"name":"testing", "email":"testing@@test.com", "password":"Passw0rd"}'
)), array());
```